# Extract Information from Drawing Image . Node and dimension . (PYTHON - OPENCV°

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, drawing, information-extraction

**[!**[Here is the picture drawing**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jY0d.jpg)]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jY0d.jpg)I'm working on a project where I need to extract the information that exists on this image. There are nodes and dimensions and between 2 nodes there is a dimension, I want to extract this information and store it in an excel file i.e. I need 3 columns. The first column is called from ie the name of the starting node and the second column is the name of the arrival node and the 3rd column is dimension. I have node position and dimension position.

**How I can link each 2 nodes with their dimension and store them in an excel file. please help me**

the text in blue represents the name of the nodes and in black the dimension.

Here is the code I used to detect and extract the nodes.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import pandas as pd 

# Load image
img = cv2.imread("black_lines_result2.jpg")

# Convert to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Set blue color range in HSV
lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 50])
upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])

# Filter blue color pixels in image
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
img=cv2.imwrite('text blue.jpg',mask)
img=cv2.imread('text blue.jpg')
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu = True)
results = reader.readtext(img)
df=pd.DataFrame(results,columns=['bbox','text','confidence'])
print(df)
```

Here is the code to extract the dimension

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import pandas as pd

# Charger l'image
img = cv2.imread("black_lines_result2.jpg")

# Convertir en espace de couleur HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Définir la plage de couleurs noires en HSV
lower_black = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_black = np.array([180, 255, 30])

# Filtrer les pixels de couleur noire dans l'image
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_black, upper_black)
cv2.imwrite('noir.jpg',mask)
# Appliquer un traitement morphologique pour améliorer les résultats de détection
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Inverser les couleurs de l'image pour obtenir du texte blanc sur fond noir
inverted_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Utiliser EasyOCR pour détecter le texte
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=True)
results = reader.readtext(inverted_mask)

# Créer un DataFrame avec les résultats
data = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['bbox', 'text', 'confidence'])
4# Parcourir chaque élément de la colonne 'text'
for i, text in enumerate(data['text']):
    # Supprimer les textes qui ne contiennent que des alphabets
    # Supprimer les textes qui ont une longueur supérieure à 10 caractères
    if len(text) > 3:
        data.drop(i, inplace=True)
print(data)
```